# How to plot an image file on a 3D graph surface using Python? - not plotting as a flat plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to plot an image file on a 3D graph surface using Python?

I have seen a couple of ways of plotting this as a plane but I would like the image to drape over the surface of the plot. Is this possible?

Comment: this question might be a bit too broad as it currently is ... you might want to add information: what image? what graph? do you have an example of the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Not with matplotlib's 3D plotting.  It's possible with Mayavi/mlab, however.  If you'd like I can give an example.

Comment: Hi Julien, I am trying to photograph a site and then drape it over topographic data.

Comment: Joe,I would be really interested to have a look at an example if you have one.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the color of your surface to be the color of the image as in this example suggested by @sarwar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
from matplotlib._png import read_png
import numpy as np

fn = get_sample_data("lena.png", asfileobj=False)
img = read_png(fn)

x, y = np.mgrid[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]]

ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, np.sin(0.02*x)*np.sin(0.02*y), rstride=2, cstride=2,
                facecolors=img)
plt.show()
```

That gives as result

[image]